# Is there a word for excessive greed?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that would describe someone who is not just greedy but would go to extremes, someone who could take away the last piece of bread from starving children. Someone who is like a scrooge, thing is - one does not say *scroogy*...

I was thinking *parsimonious* but it still sounds a bit too light...

**Is there a word for excessive greed?**

Comment: scrooge is a miser  ... but miserly and greedy are different

Comment: if you want word for a pathological sort of greed I might use Avarice .. you could look up synonyms for greed pretty easily on your own.

Comment: @Tom22 I mean in the sense that he is so greedy that could take away last peace of bread from starving children...

Comment: @Tom22 Avaricious! brilliant. Thanks Tom.

Comment: **rapacious**:Aggressively greedy or grasping.[https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rapacious]

Comment: Parsimonious is not greedy (to take and hold onto selfishly), but stingy (fearful in giving, close to miserly).

Comment: I'm not sure but why would there need to be? How can greed in and of itself be anything but excessive?

Greed is by definition different from hunger, want or need, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's always [Wikisaurus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:greedy). It's spotty but easily fixed as you go when you find words missing.

In any case, *scrooge-like* and *parsimonious* are synonyms for being pathologically *frugal*, not greedy. Scrooge earned every penny he had. The problem was seeing money as the goal instead of a means towards improving life for himself and others.

Pathological greed is ***rapaciousness***.

Answer (score 1):

See **Avarice**, defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avarice) as

> excessive or insatiable desire for wealth or gain :  greediness, cupidity